# Safari reports screen.orientation.angle opposite to standard

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

For a while I have detected orientation using this snippet:

```
const orientation = screen.orientation && screen.orientation.angle || window.orientation
```

Safari didn't support `screen.orientation` and fell back to `window.orientation` (considered deprecated by other browsers).

However, at some point in the last few months Safari started supporting `screen.orientation`...but reporting the angles backwards (other mobile browsers consider 90 degrees to mean "rotated 90 degrees to the left", but Safari considers 90 degrees to mean "rotated 90 degrees to the right").

Is there a good way to handle this? I could check the user agent, but I understand that can be pretty brittle.

EDIT: I am testing Safari on an iPhone 12 Mini, and Firefox/Chrome on a Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact.

Comment: Could you tell us which devices you are seeing that apparent discrepancy on?

Comment: I'm seeing it on an iPhone 12 mini, using the built-in Safari browser. That's my only Apple device. I've also tested it on an old Android phone using Firefox/Chrome, but the browsers on Android followed the standard.

Comment: Would detecting screen.orientation.type be more reliable? I don’t have an android device to try it on, nor do I know what some devices would think of as ‘primary and ‘secondary’ but I understand it in relation to my iPad!

Comment: Just tried that - my iPhone and Android report landscape primary/secondary opposite to each other.

Comment: I’m not sure what ‘opposite’ means here. On my iPad for example primary portrait means the edge with the home button is lower down than the edge opposite it. How is primary on an Android defined?

Comment: On Android, when the screen is rotated anti-clockwise it is reported as "landscape-primary". On iPhone, this is reported as "landscape-secondary".